# Using quotation marks as output in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

After creating some histograms with Gnuplot there is one thing I wanna add:

> quotation marks

I wanna add them to `set xlabel` but I found no answer to this. Is there a possible way?

Comment: The usual quoting/escape rules apply.  You can use single quotes inside double quotes, or double quotes inside single quotes, or prefix the problematic quote character with one or more backslash escape characters.  If you have tried that and it didn't work, please show the command you used.

Comment: It works (without escape) - thanks for the hint